# What's the difference between open and sysopen in Perl?

Tags: perl

It seems both do the same thing, huh?

Can someone show me an example where they do different job?

Comment: It's not an internal difference, it's an external difference, like Blagovest Buyukliev said.

Comment: @lexer, I've added a bit more explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 18):

`sysopen` is a thin wrapper around the `open(2)` kernel system call (the arguments correspond directly), whereas `open` is a higher-level wrapper which enables you to do redirections, piping, etc.

Unless you are working with a specific device that requires some special flags to be passed at `open(2)` time, for ordinary files on disk you should be fine with `open`.

Comment: I still don't see the difference though

Comment: @lexer: there's really nothing more to say - the rest is to understand what a system call is, and what the particular interface of `open(2)` is, all of which is OS stuff, not Perl-specific.

Comment: @lexer: The answer is spot on. In case you need a real-life exapmle, consider `O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_CREAT` combo, i.e. "create and write if not exists". Using `-f ... or open ...` instead is just asking for race condition.

Answer (score 12):

To quote [*perlopentut*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Open-agrave-la-C):

> If you want the convenience of the shell, then Perl's open is
>   definitely the way to go. On the other hand, if you want finer
>   precision than C's simplistic fopen(3S) provides you should look to
>   Perl's sysopen, which is a direct hook into the open(2) system call.
>   That does mean it's a bit more involved, but that's the price of
>   precision.

Since Perl is written in C, both methods likely end up making the `open(2)` system call. The difference is that `open()` in Perl has some niceties built in that make **opening**, **piping** and **redirection** *very* easy. At the same time, though, `open()` takes away some flexibility. It has none of the `Fcntl` functionality available in `sysopen()`, nor does it have the masking functionality.

Most situations just need `open()`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `Fcntl` and masking functionality available in `sysopen`?

Comment: There are some great examples of masks here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Permissions-agrave-la-mode , and the section in the same link just above where the link lands has great examples of the `Fcntl` features. That section begins with the phrase "And here are things you can do with sysopen that you cannot do with a regular open." Enjoy!